# Configurar .gitignore para no dar seguimiento a determinados archivos dentro de un directorio

Tags: git, gitignore

estoy intentando configurar el archivo `.gitignore` dentro de mi repositorio para dar seguimiento solo a determinados archivos en un directorio. Hasta ahora lo que tengo es esto, pero no funciona como deseo:

```
node_modules/*
node_modules/@themingisprose/icon-pack/*
!node_modules/@themingisprose/icon-pack/variables.scss
!node_modules/@themingisprose/icon-pack/style.scss
!node_modules/@themingisprose/icon-pack/svg/
!node_modules/@themingisprose/icon-pack/fonts/
!/node_modules/bootstrap/
```

En este caso, solo quiero seguir las modificaciones de los archivos cuyos patrones comienzan con `!`, pero si por ejemplo, dentro del directorio `icon-pack/` modifico el `README.md` git lo ve como modificado.

He buscado en diferentes foros y las soluciones son más o menos lo que tengo, pero no me funciona.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que ya has agregado estos archivos y ahora los quieres ignorar, entonces lo que debes hacer es:

```
git rm "nombre del archivo"
```

eso lo elimanara y ahora debes agregagarloa  tu gitignore

```
 */directorio/*
```

eso hara que no incluya ningun archivo dentro de ese directorio

tambine puedes usar:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

para no dar seguimiento a estos archivos

Comment: En realidad es un poco más complicado, solo puse un ejemplo sencillo.

En realidad tengo un proyecto en GitHub que depende de varios plugins, entre ellos este Icon Pack, que también es mio, además de Bootstrap y jQuery.

El asunto es que solo quiero dar seguimiento a los archivos que realmente necesito, porque por ejemplo jQuery cuando lo instalas vía npm baja muchos archivos que realmente no necesito.

En fin, que lo que quiero es bajar a mi repositorio local las dependencias que necesito, pero cuando haga un git push a GitHub solo suban los archivos necesarios, no todo el paquete.